# Creating a table in a Richtextbox using Rtf

Tags: c#, rtf

I've been on this for the whole day now. I would like to have a table in a Richtextbox with these columns:

```
ITEMS                  |   QTY  |  Amount  |    
Sample 1               |    1   |  100.00  |
Another Sample Here    |    3   |  300.00  |
And A Sample Here      |    4   |  400.00  |
```

I have gotten to this point

```
var tableRtf = new StringBuilder();

        tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1 ");
        tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1\pc \qc \b SOME NAME \b0 \par}");
        tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1\pc \qc SOME TYPE \par}");
        tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1\pc \qc SOMEWHERE IN THE CITY, SOMETHING ADDRESS, SOMETHING CITY \par}");
        tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1\pc \qc TEL. NUM. 1234567 \par}");
        tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1\pc \qc VAT-REG TIN 200-035-311-0010 \par}");
        tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1\pc \par}");

        for (var i = 0; i < listOrderedItems.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var x = listOrderedItems.Items[i].Text;
                var y = listOrderedItems.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text;
                var q = listOrderedItems.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;

                tableRtf.Append(@"\trowd");

                //A cell with width 4000.
                tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx4000");
                //Another cell with width 1000
                tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx5000");
                //Another cell with width 1000
                tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx6000");

                tableRtf.Append(String.Format(@"\intbl {0} \cell {1} \cell {2} \cell \row",x,q,y)); //create row

            }

            tableRtf.Append(@"\pard");

            tableRtf.Append(@"}");

            this.txtReceipt.Rtf = tableRtf.ToString();
```

How do I put the column headers and how do I center the text in the second and third columns only? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a different suggestion as opposed to a solution per se, but you could put the text in a mono spaced font - for example Courier new, find out the longest any one bit of data in a column is going to be and then create a fake table from it with `String.PadRight(int totalWidth)` to align all the values. With this you can just add a separator between each padded column

Comment: What your suggesting sounds good but it may be too complicated for me already. I'm a newbie. I understand my code and it gives me the right output. It's just that I can still make it better by putting header titles and centering the values in the columns.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to directly hard code the column header or insert column header and data from a DataTable into a created table in RichTextBox control.

For example : **dtbl** is a datatable which we can trasfer in to richtextbox table.
              **tableRtf** is a text string.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <dtbl.Columns.Count; j++)
 {
     //A cell with width 1000. 
     tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx" + ((i+1) * 1000).ToString());

     if (i == 0)
     tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl  " + dtbl.Columns[i].ColumnName);
     else
     tableRtf.Append(@"\cell   " + dtbl.Columns[i].ColumnName);
  }
```

For more details Check out the link  [add text to created table Richtextbox](http://www.dotnetstuffs.com/how-to-add-text-in-a-created-table-in-a-richtextbox/)